# Merging multiple cell in SQL Server to a single cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to merge certain values from a same table in to a single output.

Let's say I have the following data:

[image]

While saving the details in the database I am saving them separately but I am going to call this info as `cus_address` as a single cell as temporary table just to use at the instance of the call which should retrieve as (84, vanapadi road, ranipet-632403, india)

I tried using the '+' operator in it and it worked

```
select Street + City + Postalcode + Country as cust_address
from Shipping_Label_details_Old'
```

[image]

This is OK but I need to add spacing's and - before the postal code stuffs.

Comment: select Street + City + Postalcode + Country as cust_address from Shipping_Label_details_Old this i what  tried and getting the desired out put but the spacing and the '-' for pincode is what i am unable to add

Comment: `select street+', '+city+'-'+CAST(postalcode as VARCHAR(30)+', '+country)`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the `strings` using `+`:

```
SELECT Street + ', ' + postalCode + ', ' + City + ', ' + Country AS cus_address 
FROM tbl
```

And if the `postalCode` column is of any type other than `string`, for example `int`, first you need to cast it to `string` (`varchar`):

```
SELECT Street + ', ' + CAST(postalCode AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + City + ', ' + Country AS cus_address 
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Street + ', ' + City + '-' + Postalcode + ', ' + Country
from PlaceTable
```

[image]